# Split text, leave out elements in braces

Tags: python, regex

I need to split a string like:

`aaaa b aaaa {aaa b aaa} aaa b aaa`

by the 'b' element, but not the parts in the braces. This is not html or xml, so I didn't try any module.

The 'aaa' means arbitrary text.

The result should look like:

`['aaa', 'b', 'aaaa {aaa b aaa} aaa', 'b', 'aaa']`

Still can not figure out the regexp. 
I understand, that 'lookbehind' construction `(?<!...)` doesn't work, because the text in braces may have different length.
I had to try `[^{]*?(b)[^}]*?` formula, but it still captures "b" in braces.
Can't think of anything else. Please help.

UPD: I parse a long line (including EOLs), so being not able to match "b" at the start or end of line seems not to be a problem ("b" is not there anyway). Adding re.S (dotted) flag to the re.compile() should do the trick.

Comment: What about the spaces?

Comment: Your question is too under-specified, it is hardly useful for anyone apart from you.

Comment: 2Avinash Raj: I'll have to strip() white spaces from resulting strings anyway, so I figured, that it's not important if they are included into text ' aaa ' or separator ' b ' elements of resulting list. I was wrong, of course. But I'm uncomfortable with too complicated REs. Have to understand them better.

Comment: As always you might look at the problem differently. I think it's far more easier to match instead of splitting. [**See demo**](https://regex101.com/r/hK7gP2/1). Now in case that "b" might be a "str" or anything else more than one character, you could use something like [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/hK7gP2/2). Of course, you might trim the spaces afterwards.

Comment: Thank you. I rarely use 'match', seems too tricky. Besides, I need to capture 'b's, not dismiss them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.split`

```
(?<!})\s(?!{|[^{]*})(?=b)|(?<=b)\s(?!{|[^{]*})
```

https://regex101.com/r/gQ3kS4/14

Answer (score 1):

Since the requirement is not very clear, I make a lot of assumptions in this solution, which I don't even know if it holds in your input:

```
>>> re.split(r"(?:^|\s*\b)(b)(?:\s+(?![^{}]*})|$)", "aaaa b aaaa {aaa b aaa} aaa b aaa")
['aaaa', 'b', 'aaaa {aaa b aaa} aaa', 'b', 'aaa']

>>> re.split(r"(?:^|\s*\b)(b)(?:\s+(?![^{}]*})|$)", "b aaaa b b aaaa {aaa b aaa} aaa b aaa b")
['', 'b', 'aaaa', 'b', '', 'b', 'aaaa {aaa b aaa} aaa', 'b', 'aaa', 'b', '']
```

I just make sure the `b` to be used as delimiter is not followed by "normal text" (or more precisely, any character not curly bracket `[^{}]`) then a closing curly bracket `}`.

I capture `(b)`, so it that appears in the resulting array.

To take care of the surrounding spaces, I need to consume the spaces around them if any, which is the reason for the complexity in the regex above.

### Old solution

Here is my original (simpler) solution, which works for your input:

```
>>> re.split(r"\s+(b)\s+(?![^{}]*})", "aaaa b aaaa {aaa b aaa} aaa b aaa")
['aaaa', 'b', 'aaaa {aaa b aaa} aaa', 'b', 'aaa']
```

However, it fails on cases where `b` is at the beginning of the string, the end of the string, or there are 2 consecutive `b` entries:

```
>>> re.split(r"\s+(b)\s+(?![^{}]*})",  "b aaaa b b aaaa {aaa b aaa} aaa b aaa b")
['b aaaa', 'b', 'b aaaa {aaa b aaa} aaa', 'b', 'aaa b']
```

Comment: This doesn't pick up `b` at the start and end of the string, e.g. `b a b` won't be split at all.

Comment: @Rawing: Should work for that case now, but the OP is not very clear about this.

Comment: I know. I just wanted to point it out so OP knows what his pattern does if he chooses to pick this one, that's all.

Comment: Actually I parse a long line (including EOLs), so that seems not to be a problem. I suppose, adding re.S (dotted) flag to the re.compile() should do the trick.

Comment: @paul_k: `re.S` has no effect on my pattern, afaik for Python `re`.

Comment: Right. Those multiline flags still a bit of a mystery to me. Your old RE is quite sufficient for my task, so far. Using more complicated structure seems to be an 'overkill'. Sorry, I didn't give you more exact description of this task at first.

Answer (score 0):

It's so hard to figure out through default `re` module. So i used the external `regex` module.

```
>>> s = "aaaa b aaaa {aaa b aaa} aaa b aaa"
>>> regex.split(r'\s(?=b(?:\s|$)(?![^{}]*}))|(?<=(?:^|\s)b)\s(?![^{}]*})', s)
['aaaa', 'b', 'aaaa {aaa b aaa} aaa', 'b', 'aaa']
>>> s = "b a bbb b bbb bbb"
>>> regex.split(r'\s(?=b(?:\s|$)(?![^{}]*}))|(?<=(?:^|\s)b)\s(?![^{}]*})', s)
['b', 'a bbb', 'b', 'bbb bbb']
```

Comment: This is a bit flawed - it won't split `b a b` (it doesn't pick up `b`s at the start and end of the text).

Answer (score 0):

You can use look-ahead too.

```
>>> a = 'aaaa b aaaa {aaa b aaa} aaa b aaa'
>>> re.split("\s*(b)\s*(?![\w ]*})", a)
['aaaa', 'b', 'aaaa {aaa b aaa} aaa', 'b', 'aaa']
```

In this case it works if you don't care a ton about extra whitespace.

Comment: There are spaces in your output.

Answer (score -1):

As long as there are no nested braces, that's a simple one:

```
>>> x="aaaa b aaaa {aaa b aaa} aaa b aaa"
>>> re.findall(r'\S+(?:\s*\{.*?\}\s*)?\S*',x)
['aaaa', 'b', 'aaaa {aaa b aaa} aaa', 'b', 'aaa']
```

Comment: i didn't find any `b` in your regex.